# How can I return to the previous page that contains fragments in its URL?

Tags: php, hash, fragment, http-referer

How can I return to the previous page that contains fragments in its URL?

For instance, this is the previous page,

> http://localhost/website.com/#/story/article-title-2/

And this is the current page,

> http://localhost/website.com/article-title-2/

In this current page I have a back button to return to the previous page.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];?>">Back &gt;</a>
```

But `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` returns to the root page instead of the previous page,

> http://localhost/website.com/

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Your problem is the # in the url.

Comment: fragments aren't sent to the server. they're purely a client-side thing. You'll need some javascript to preserve them, and/or manipulate the history object.

Comment: You could use that old crummy `javascript:history.go(-1);`

Comment: Here is my two cents on preserving fragments in the face of redirects (e.g. for authentication) http://tshrestha.blogspot.com/2013/05/hash-bang-url-fragments-and-http.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<a href="javascript:history.go(-1);">back</a>`
or
`<a href="javascript:history.back();">back</a>`
however if you can try not to use inline javascript....

I cannot see a simple way to do this via PHP..